# Are value parameters implicitly moved when returned by value?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, move-semantics, c++11

Consider the following function:

```
Foo foo(Foo x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Will `return x` invoke the copy constructor or the move constructor? (Let's leave NRVO aside here.)

To investigate, I wrote a simple `Foo` class that is only movable but not copyable:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
};
```

If the move constructor were invoked when returning value parameters by value, all should be fine. But the current g++ compiler complains about `return x` with the following error message:

```
error: deleted function 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
```

If I replace `return x` with `return std::move(x)`, everything is fine. From this I conclude that moving from value parameters must be done explicitly if desired. Is g++'s behavior conforming or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If there is a move ctor for Foo, it should be selected.

Function parameters are explicitly excluded from copy elision in return statements (FDIS §12.9p31, first bullet):

> - in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object **(other than a function or catch-clause parameter)**

However, the next paragraph explicitly brings move ctors back into consideration:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or **would be met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter**, and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed **as if the object were designated by an rvalue**. …

(Emphasis is mine in both quotes.)

Comment: Upvoted.  This was a relatively late change to the draft which explains why it isn't implemented everywhere yet.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1148

Answer (score 12):

This is valid code- G++'s behaviour is non-conformant. MSVC10 does support this behaviour.

Comment: while I respect your investigation, you do not justify the "valid" here. MSVC is reknown for being lax and allowing some (convenient) slips that the standard forbids (binding non-const references and specializing member functions within the class body, for example).

Comment: @Matthieu: I didn't say that it was valid *because* MSVC10 supported it. It's valid because the Standard says so.

Comment: I understood, but there is still no justification :)

Comment: @Matthieu: The question didn't ask for a Standard quote, it asked for yes or no.