# Operator keyword c++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

We have following class. I need explanation of some parts of code.

```
class CPoint3D
    {
    public:
      double x, y, z;

      CPoint3D (double dX = 0.0, double dY = 0.0, double dZ = 0.0) 
              : x(dX), y(dY), z(dZ) {}
      //what means these lines of    code?
      CPoint3D operator + (const CPoint3D& point) const;
      CPoint3D operator - (const CPoint3D& point) const;
      CPoint3D operator * (double dFactor) const;
      CPoint3D operator / (double dFactor) const;
};
```

I guess using

`CPoint3D operator + (const CPoint3D& point) const;`

function I can easily add/subtract/multiply/divide instances of `CPoint3D` class?

Can someone explain this with examples ?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to know how to use the operators or how to implement them?

Comment: There is an [epic question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) that explains everything quite well.

Comment: @Nurlan if you got an answer here, please accept it, to help others who read the question in future. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

There are millions of examples and/or articles of this on the web (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)) so I won't re-iterate them here.

Suffice to say that when you add together two `CPoint3D` objects with `obj1 + obj2`, the function that gets called is `operator+` for that class, with one object being `this` and the other being `point`.

Your code is responsible for creating another object containing the addition of those two, then returning it.

Ditto for the subtraction. The multiplicative operators are *slightly* different since they use a double as the other argument - presumably while it makes some sense to add/subtract individual members of your class for the additive operators, that's not as useful for the multiplicative ones.

Answer (score 4):

You may read some literature regarding [C++ operator overloading](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_overloading.html). Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading), or [here](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html), or just Google it :)

Here is a simple example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/):

```
// vectors: overloading operators example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};
    CVector (int,int);
    CVector operator + (CVector);
};

CVector::CVector (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return (temp);
}

int main () {
  CVector a (3,1);
  CVector b (1,2);
  CVector c;
  c = a + b;
  cout << c.x << "," << c.y;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe take const CPoint3D& point for the operator + as the OP does?

Comment: Well, the types of the arguments of overloaded non-assignment operators don't actually matter at all. They don't have to make any sense! This is not like copy/move constructors/assignment operators, where the argument must be one of the defined kinds of of _lvalue_ representing the same type so as to be considered a 'real' copy/move. But for any larger object, passing by `const &` reference would be more efficient. The example here, containing 2 basic types, I _think_ is right on the border where careful benchmarking would be required to prove whether passing by-copy or -ref is more efficient.

Comment: Btw, since the argument is by-value, if anyone wonders why this answer didn't just add to and return _that_, a good reason - which I presume Didac had in mind! - is that arguments are exempt from named return value optimisation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6009278/2757035 So whereas you might think it's slow to create a temporary and add to it instead - doing so enables the compiler to (perhaps!) perform the large transformations inherent in RVO and obtain a much more efficient result by constructing `temp` directly at the call site, instead of literally returning a value that has to be copied.