# Guaranteed elision and chained function calls

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision

Let's say I have the following type:

```
struct X {
    X& operator+=(X const&);
    friend X operator+(X lhs, X const& rhs) {
        lhs += rhs;
        return lhs;
    }
};
```

And I have the declaration (assume all the named variables are lvalues of type `X`):

```
X sum = a + b + c + d;
```

In C++17, what are the guarantees I have about how many copies and moves this expression will perform? What about non-guaranteed elision?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will perform 1 copy construction and 3 move constructions.

1. Make a copy of `a` to bind to `lhs`.
2. Move construct `lhs` out of the first `+`.
3. The return of the first `+` will bind to the by value `lhs` parameter of the second `+` with elision.
4. The return of the second `lhs` will incur the second move construction.
5. The return of the third `lhs` will incur the third move construction.
6. The temporary returned from the third `+` will be constructed at `sum`.

For each of the move constructions described above, there is another move construction that is optionally elided.  So you are only *guaranteed* to have 1 copy and 6 moves.  But in practice, unless you `-fno-elide-constructors`, you will have 1 copy and 3 moves.

If you don't reference `a` after this expression, you could further optimize with:

```
X sum = std::move(a) + b + c + d;
```

resulting in 0 copies and 4 moves (7 moves with `-fno-elide-constructors`).

The above results have been confirmed with an `X` which has instrumented copy and move constructors.

---

**Update**

If you're interested in different ways to optimize this, you could start with overload the lhs on `X const&` and `X&&`:

```
friend X operator+(X&& lhs, X const& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return std::move(lhs);
}
friend X operator+(X const& lhs, X const& rhs) {
    auto temp = lhs;
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

This gets things down to 1 copy and 2 moves.  If you are willing to restrict your clients from ever catching the return of your `+` by reference, then you can return `X&&` from one of the overloads like this:

```
friend X&& operator+(X&& lhs, X const& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return std::move(lhs);
}
friend X operator+(X const& lhs, X const& rhs) {
    auto temp = lhs;
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

Getting you down to 1 copy and 1 move.  Note that in this latest design, if you client ever does this:

```
X&& x = a + b + c;
```

then `x` is a dangling reference (which is why `std::string` does not do this).

Comment: So no chaining of elision? e.g. constructing the return of `a+b` directly into `operator+(??, c)`?

Comment: I don't even think it is legal to elide the return of `lhs`.  However I also don't think any of the compiler writers have had any motivation to make it legal (no one attempts it anyway).

Comment: Why it may be illegal? Can it became legal in the future?

Comment: @Orient:  What I was trying to say is that the standard does not allow it.  No one to my knowledge has ever proposed it.  And I suspect the reason for that is that no one has figured out how to implement it.  But those are guesses, I am not a compiler expert.

Answer (score 9):

OK, let's start with this:

```
X operator+(X lhs, X const& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

This will *always* provoke a copy/move from the parameter to the return value object. C++17 doesn't change this, and no form of elision can avoid this copy.

Now, let's look at one part of your expression: `a + b`. Since the first parameter of `operator+` is taken by value, `a` must be *copied* into it. So that's one copy. The return value will be copied out into the return prvalue. So that's 1 copy and one move/copy.

Now, the next part: `(a + b) + c`.

C++17 means that the prvalue returned from `a + b` will be used to directly initialize the parameter of `operator+`. This requires no copying/moving. But the return value from this will be copied from that parameter. So that's 1 copy and 2 moves/copies.

Repeat this for the last expression, and that's 1 copy and 3 move/copies. `sum` will be initialized from the prvalue expression, so no copying needs to be done there.

---

Your question really seems to be whether parameters *remain* excluded from elision in C++17. Because [they were already excluded in prior versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6009278/734069). And that's not going to change; the reasons for excluding parameters from elision have not been invalidated.

"Guaranteed elision" *only applies* to prvalues. If it has a name, it *cannot* be a prvalue.

Comment: Some of these are going to be moves though - you mean 1 copy and 3 moves?

Comment: To put Nicol's comment about the parameter copy differently: taking an argument by value only helps for copy elision on the way in and *only* makes sense when *consuming* the parameter, i.e., `std::move()`ing it elsewhere, e.g.: `X rc(std::move(lhs)); rc += rhs; return rc;`

Comment: @Barry: Yes, I forgot that moves from returning local variables are automatic.

Comment: I guess it'd've been cool if this whole thing could compile into the equivalent of `X sum(a); sum += b; sum += c; sum += d;` Guess that's still pretty hard.