# Dangling reference when returning reference to reference parameter bound to temporary

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, temporary-objects, return-by-reference

This question refers to Howard Hinnant's answer to the question [Guaranteed elision and chained function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165907/guaranteed-elision-and-chained-function-calls).

At the bottom of his answer, he says:

> Note that in this latest design, if your client ever does this:
>
> ```cpp
> X&& x = a + b + c;
> ```
>
> then x is a dangling reference (which is why std::string does not do this).

The paragraph "Lifetime of a temporary" of the article "Reference initialization" on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) lists exceptions to the lifetime rules of temporary objects bound to a reference. One being:

> "a temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference."

I think it is rather meant "if the function returns a reference **to the temporary object the reference parameter is bound to**", not just some other reference. As a consequence, I reckon this is the rule that explains Howard Hinnant's above-mentioned statement.

The following example is based on the example given in the question that I am referring to:

```cpp
struct X
{
    int _x;
    X() : _x(0) {}
    X(int x) : _x(x) {}
    X(X const& other) : _x(other._x) {}
    X(X&& other) noexcept : _x(other._x) { other._x = 0; std::cout << "Move from " << &other << " to " << this << std::endl; }
    X& operator+=(const X& other) { _x += other._x; return *this; }

    friend X operator+(X const& lhs, X const& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "X const& lhs: " << &lhs << std::endl;
        X temp = lhs;
        temp += rhs;
        return temp;
    }

    friend X&& operator+(X&& lhs, X const& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "X&& lhs: " << &lhs << std::endl;
        lhs += rhs;
        return std::move(lhs);
    }
};

int anotherFunc(int a)
{
    int bigArray[3000]{};
    std::cout << "ignore:" << &bigArray << std::endl;
    int b = a * a;
    std::cout << "int b: " << &b << std::endl;
    return 2 * b;
}

int main()
{
    X a(1), b(2), c(3), d(4);
    X&& sum = a + b + c + d;
    std::cout << "X&& sum: " << &sum << std::endl;
    anotherFunc(15);
    std::cout << "sum._x: " << sum._x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
X const& lhs: 000000907DAFF8B4
Move from 000000907DAFF794 to 000000907DAFFA14
X&& lhs: 000000907DAFFA14
X&& lhs: 000000907DAFFA14
X&& sum: 000000907DAFFA14
ignore:000000907DAFC360
int b: 000000907DAFF254
sum._x: 10
```

when compiled with MSVC; and similar outputs when compiled with gcc or clang.

`sum` should be a dangling reference here. Still, the correct value "10" is being printed. It even works when pushing a large array onto the stack between the reference initialization of `sum` and the access via said reference. The memory used for the temporary object that sum refers does not get reused and is always allocated elsewhere (in relation to the stack frame of the following function call), no matter how big or small the next stack frame is.

Why does every compiler that I've tested preserve the temporary object local to `X&& operator+(X&& lhs, X const& rhs)` even though `sum` should be a dangling reference according to the rule on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization). Or, to be more precise: Despite accessing a dangling reference being undefined behaviour, why does **every** compiler implement it that way?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You can't observe the *absence* of undefined behaviour,  and printing "10" is one of its countless possible manifestations.

Comment: I would have expected that any of these compilers would have reused the stack memory that was used for the temporary object that sum binds to. Why would they ALL preserve that temporary object if there is no rule that requires them to?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour means that the program is not subject to (logical) analysis and any attempt is a waste of time and effort.  All you can do is remove the UB and re-test. See also [Old New Thing - Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: Because function stack address space if usually calculated only once at entrance and usually does not overlap with inner function calls (but there can be tail recursion optimizations, etc.) . If you'd also print `&bigArray[3000]` you'd notice it does not overlap with `sum` address. You can maybe see the dangling reference value overwritten (if lucky enough and no optimizations enabled) with something like this: `X *psum; { X&& sum = a + b + c + d; psum = &sum;  } { int v = 42; std::cout << "&v = " << &v << " v = " << v << std::endl; } std::cout << "sum._x: " << psum->_x << std::endl;`

Comment: @Ruperrrt It's completely up to the implementation whether it will or will not reuse the stack space reserved for a temporary. Also, ABI typically prescribes some stack alignment, which may cause the stack frame of `anotherFunc` to be placed below of what you expect. Here is a live demo with defined behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/v7q1vsK1h. Note that the stack storage for temporary at `rsp+15` is not reused in `g1` call after its lifetime ends.

Comment: @RichardCritten Even with UB, it may be sometimes instructive to study the observed behavior, which is usually fully defined by the implementation-generated machine code.

Comment: @DanielLangr I have considered this (look at the generated code) but with changes to optimisation level (or other flags), compiler version, compiler vendor all affecting the generated code I don't see what practical use such knowledge would be. So I usually just advise - fix it (the UB) and move on.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! So this IS in fact UB, the rule I've quoted from cppreference is applicable here and those 3 compilers just happen to implement it that way? I was in doubt if I was missing some other rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep an example `class A` around for situations like this.  The full definition of `A` is a little too lengthy to list here, but it is included in its entirety [at this link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Ajp93egfEUEvuW2).

In a nutshell, `A` keeps a `state` and a `status`, and the `status` can be one of these enums:

```
    destructed             = -4,
    self_move_assigned     = -3,
    move_assigned_from     = -2,
    move_constructed_from  = -1,
    constructed_specified  =  0
```

That is, the special members set the status accordingly.  For example `~A()` looks like this:

```
~A()
{
    assert(is_valid());
    --count;
    state_ = randomize();
    status_ = destructed;
}
```

And there's a streaming operator that prints this class out.

*Language lawyer disclaimer:* Printing out a destructed `A` is undefined behavior, and anything could happen.  That being said, when experiments are compiled with optimizations turned **off**, you typically get the expected result.

For me, using `clang` at `-O0`, this:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    A a{1};
    A b{2};
    A c{3};
    A&& x = a + b + c;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
destructed: -1002199219
```

Changing the line to:

```
    A x = a + b + c;
```

Results in:

```
6
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question! Your class is great for examining behaviour like this.