# spawn a copy as input to function taking rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference

I have a library function (not under my control here) which take an r value reference to the movable and copyable type Bar:

```
void foo(Bar&& b);
```

In my own code, I sometimes need to give it a copy of an existing value, such as

```
const auto b = getBar();
foo(mk_copy(b));
b.baz();
```

This is what comes to mind,

```
template<typename T> auto mk_copy(T val){return val;}
```

Is there a standard way to do this, or a more common pattern? Perhaps even

```
template<typename T> auto mk_copy(T&& val){return std::forward<T>(val);}
```

Or, as pscill points out just writing the name of the class again,

```
foo(Bar(b));
```

but I prefer not to repeat type names.

Comment: How about just calling the copy constructor? `foo(Bar{b});`

Comment: `make_copy` does seem the cleanest. The prefix `make` seems to be on its way to become a convention for this kind of thing.

Comment: Why can't you just write an overload of `foo` for lvalues in the same namespace as the real library function (which internally copies and moves to the real func) so that calling code can just look perfectly natural without the `mk_copy` noise?

Comment: This is essentially `decay_copy`, which we may get one day - or not. That paper seems to have been busy falling through the cracks.

Comment: @T.C. Cool, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard mechanism, but if you want one, your examples aren't very good. The first `mk_copy` copies `T` twice (or copies and moves). The second one seems very confusing as to what it's trying to do.

The obvious way is to simply take a `const T&`, like you normally would:

```
template<typename T> T mk_copy(const T &val){return val;}
```

Comment: Isn't RVO applied for the 1st one?

Comment: @songyuanyao: No. [Elision does not apply to function parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009278/why-are-by-value-parameters-excluded-from-nrvo/9595610#9595610).

Comment: Thanks. The first, does a copy and a move no? The second one is supposed to make a single copy, but optimize to a single move if possible. A bit of overkill but is it wrong? I admit I didn't think it through.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: A copy followed by a copy/move, depending on what `T` can do.

Comment: Revisited: "The second one seems very confusing as to what it's trying to do". As T.C. points out this is also the same (minus some conditionals ) as decay_copy, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3255.html.

Answer (score 1):

For the built-in types the prefix `+` plays the role of “make a copy”:

```
void foo( char&& ) {}
void bar( double*&& ) {}

auto main() -> int
{
    char x{};
    foo( +x );

    double* p{};
    bar( +p );
}
```

Still, it would probably be confusing to readers of the code if you applied prefix `+` to some other type, and a general prefix `operator+` template might end up in conflict with some class' own prefix `operator+`.

So, I suggest using the now apparent naming convention for makers, namely a `make` prefix.

Then it can look like this:

```
template< class Type >
auto make_copy( Type const& o ) -> Type { return o; }
```

---

Your first proposed solution,

```
template<typename T> auto mk_copy(T val){return val;}
```

suffers from potentially copying the value twice: first copying to the by-value argument, and then copying to the function result.

This is not a problem for a movable type such as a standard library container, because the return type copying will reduce to a move. But it can be a problem for largish non-movable type, as can occur in legacy code.

---

The second proposed solution,

```
template<typename T> auto mk_copy(T&& val){return std::forward<T>(val);}
```

takes the argument by forwarding reference (a.k.a. universal reference), and then deduces the return type from a re-creation of the argument type. The return type will always be a non-reference, since that's what plain `auto` deduces, so this is technically correct. But it's needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better just define that `mk_copy` method, or add one more declaration:

```
auto b_copy = b;
foo(std::move(b_copy));
```

These are clearer to the readers.

---

Just to demonstrate the possibilities, you could use `decltype` to get the type:

```
foo(std::decay_t<decltype(b)>{b});
```

or you could get the same effect with lambdas:

```
foo([&]{return b;}());
```

or tuples:

```
foo(std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(b)));
```

or pairs:

```
foo(std::make_pair(b, 0).first);
```

Comment: decltype(b){b}, deduces a reference if b is a references, so that would not work.

Comment: @JohanLundberg Added `std::decay`.

Comment: Ok :). Also, I think there are only down sides with using {} for calling a copy constructor. (The class could have an initializer list constructor doing something completely different..)