How the mechanism of NRVO works in C++ function return values?
According to some sources, Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO) is performed when a return object; statement in a function is executed.
Nevertheless, the execution of
int foo(int a_func) {
   std::cout << "Address of a_func: " << &a_func << std::endl;
   return a_func;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   int a = 10;
   std::cout << "Address of a: " << &a << std::endl;

   int &&a_func_return{foo(a)};
   std::cout << "Address of a_func_return: " << &a_func_return << std::endl;

   return 0;
}

lead to
Address of a: 0x796ca0209020
Address of a_func: 0x796ca0209060
Address of a_func_return: 0x796ca0209030

If there were any copy elision, shouldn't the addresses of a_func and  a_func_return be the same?

NVRO is not applied to parameters. The complete list of cases is on Copy elision

related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009278/why-are-by-value-parameters-excluded-from-nrvo

NRVO is also unobservable if functions are inlined, if the calling convention uses registers to return an object, if the compiler decided not to do it anyways etc. You probably want to read more about NRVO, experimenting doesn't help.
